# compute the difference of all possible rows

Tags: python, pandas

Based on a selection `ds` of a dataframe `d` with:

`{ 'x': d.x, 'y': d.y, 'a':d.a, 'b':d.b, 'c':d.c 'row:d.n'})`

Having `n` rows, `x` ranges from `0` to `n-1`. The column `n` is needed since it's a selection and indices need to be kept for a later query.

How do you efficiently compute the difference between each row (e.g.`a_0, a_1, etc`) of each column (`a, b, c`) without losing the rows information (e.g. new column with the indices of the rows that were used) ?

**MWE**

Sample selection `ds`:

```
             x           y      a     b      c     n

    554.607085  400.971878   9789  4151   6837   146
    512.231450  405.469524   8796  3811   6596   225
    570.427284  694.369140   1608  2019   2097   291
```

Desired output:

`dist` euclidean distance `math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)`

`da, db, dc` for `da: np.abs(a1-a2)`

`ns` a string with both `n`s of the employed rows

the result would look like:

```
             dist          da        db       dc         ns
42.61365102824963         993       340      241    146-225
293.82347069813255       8181      2132     4740    146-291
                ..         ..        ..       ..    225-291
```

Comment: Please, put some example, provide details. Share your research.

Comment: can you post a sample dataframe and desired output?

Comment: edited for completion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.combinations()` to generate the pairs:

Read data first:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np

text = """             x           y      a     b      c     n
    554.607085  400.971878   9789  4151   6837   146
    512.231450  405.469524   8796  3811   6596   225
    570.427284  694.369140   1608  2019   2097   291"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), delim_whitespace=True)
```

Create the index and calculate the results:

```
from itertools import combinations

index = np.array(list(combinations(range(df.shape[0]), 2)))

df1, df2 = [df.iloc[idx].reset_index(drop=True) for idx in index.T]

res = pd.concat([
    np.hypot(df1.x - df2.x, df1.y - df2.y),
    df1[["a", "b", "c"]] - df2[["a", "b", "c"]],
    df1.n.astype(str) + "-" + df2.n.astype(str)
], axis=1)

res.columns = ["dist", "da", "db", "dc", "ns"]
res
```

the output:

```
         dist    da    db    dc       ns
0   42.613651   993   340   241  146-225
1  293.823471  8181  2132  4740  146-291
2  294.702805  7188  1792  4499  225-291
```

Comment: Thanks, i knew there was a better way!! :)

Answer (score 1):

This approach makes good use of Pandas and the underlying numpy capabilities, but the matrix manipulations are a little hard to keep track of:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

ds = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [554.607085, 400.971878,  9789, 4151,  6837,  146], 
        [512.231450, 405.469524,  8796, 3811,  6596,  225],
        [570.427284, 694.369140,  1608, 2019,  2097,  291]
    ],
    columns = ['x', 'y', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'n']
)

def concat_str(*arrays):
    result = arrays[0]
    for arr in arrays[1:]:
        result = np.core.defchararray.add(result, arr)
    return result

# Make a panel with one item for each column, with a square data frame for 
# each item, showing the differences between all row pairs.
# This creates perpendicular matrices of values based on the underlying numpy arrays;
# then numpy broadcasts them along the missing axis when calculating the differences
p = pd.Panel(
    (ds.values[np.newaxis,:,:] - ds.values[:,np.newaxis,:]).transpose(), 
    items=['d'+c for c in ds.columns], major_axis=ds.index, minor_axis=ds.index
)
# calculate euclidian distance
p['dist'] = np.hypot(p['dx'], p['dy'])
# create strings showing row relationships
p['ns'] = concat_str(ds['n'].values.astype(str)[:,np.newaxis], '-', ds['n'].values.astype(str)[np.newaxis,:])
# remove unneeded items
del p['dx'], p['dy'], p['dn']
# convert to frame
diffs = p.to_frame().reindex_axis(['dist', 'da', 'db', 'dc', 'ns'], axis=1)
diffs
```

This gives:

```
                   dist    da    db    dc       ns
major minor                                       
0     0        0.000000     0     0     0  146-146
      1       42.613651   993   340   241  146-225
      2      293.823471  8181  2132  4740  146-291
1     0       42.613651  -993  -340  -241  225-146
      1        0.000000     0     0     0  225-225
      2      294.702805  7188  1792  4499  225-291
2     0      293.823471 -8181 -2132 -4740  291-146
      1      294.702805 -7188 -1792 -4499  291-225
      2        0.000000     0     0     0  291-291
```